# Getting "createContext only works in Client Components" while using createIntl

Tags: next.js, next.js13, react-intl, app-router, formatjs

I'm using NextJS 13 with the app router. In a server action I'm trying to obtain localized text. For this I've created the following function:

```
import { createIntl, createIntlCache, IntlShape } from "react-intl";
import { SupportedLocale } from "@/types/locale";

const cache = createIntlCache();

export const getIntlForBackend = (locale: SupportedLocale): IntlShape => {
  return createIntl(
    {
      locale,
      defaultLocale: SupportedLocale.SPANISH,
      messages: {},
    },
    cache
  );
};
```

My understanding is that `createIntl` is made for these types of scenarios (backend code in which React context is not available.

From https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api): **createIntl*: In a non-React environment (Node, vue, angular, testing... you name it), you can directly create a intl object by calling this function with the same configuration as the IntlProvider.*

Despite this I'm getting the following error:

`Unhandled Runtime Error Error: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component`

I've traced the calls from the start of the server action until this function is called, and I'm sure it's this that is causing it.

For example I can replace

```
const intl = getIntlForBackend(locale);
```

with

```
const intl = {
  formatMessage: (a: any, b: any) => "testing",
};
```

and no longer get the error and the code in the server action completes successfully.

Any tips on what could be happening? Ty!

Comment: Exactly what the error says. `createIntl` internally calls `createContext`. This is only allowed in Client component and you obviously call it from a Server component. Add `'use client'` at the top of the file where you call `createIntl` and all should be fine.

Comment: Would you say the docs are wrong? They explicitly mention `createIntl` is for non-React environments such as Node. If so, is there another way to obtain a similar `intl` object for use in the server?

Comment: non-React or not, it uses createContext somehow and you cannot do this in Server Component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that you shouldn't import from `react-intl` but from `@formatjs/intl`:

```
import { createIntl, createIntlCache, IntlShape } from "@formatjs/intl";
```